# DirectX 9 Fixed Function Textures

Tags: c++, graphics, directx-9

Using the Fixed Function rendering pipeline in DirectX 9, it's quite easy to set a texture and render vertices by doing the following:

```
struct vert { float x, y, z, u, v; };

device->SetFVF(D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_TEX1);
device->SetTexture(0, MyTexture);

//Draw vertices here
```

However, I'd like to add an additional float value to each vertex, which is then multiplied by the resulting colour output from the texture. (So the value would be between 0 and 1)

EG (psuedocode) `Colour = TextureColour(u, v) * CustomFloat`

I think there is a way using `device->SetTextureStageState`, but I am unsure of how to do it... Can anyone help me?

Comment: strongly related to [Per vertex pre-computated lighting in DirectX9 using fixed function rendering pipeline.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982929/per-vertex-pre-computated-lighting-in-directx9-using-fixed-function-rendering-pip) -while not exactly a duplicate, an answer to that would answer this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a 1D linear grayscale texture as a second texture, configured to modulate the first. Then send a single texture coordinate for the second texture (by specifying D3DFVF_TEXCOORDSIZE1 for it, I think). Speculating here -- haven't tried it myself.

To paraphrase your pseudocode: `Colour = Texture0Colour(u0, v0) * Texture1Colour(u1)`

**Edit** I think you need:

```
device->SetFVF(D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_TEX2 | D3DFVF_TEXCOORDSIZE2(0) | D3DFVF_TEXCOORDSIZE1(1))
```

MSDN also has [a similar example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172560%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Sounds good, but can you have vertices with 2d and 1d textures? (I don't think you can get D3DFVF_TEXTUREFORMAT2 and D3DFVF_TEXTUREFORMAT1)...

Comment: 2D UV are common in vertices, and you can have two pairs of UVs, by using D3DFVF_TEX2, and you can easily use 2D UV to address a 1D texture. Note: A pair of UVs is 8 B, and therefore still takes more bandwidth than D3DFVF_DIFFUSE. Other than that, this solution is smart, easy to understand and you should be able to get it running.

Comment: Yes, you can have different texture dimensions in the same vertex format. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

This could hopefully get you started: [Per-Vertex Color State (Direct3D 9)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147265%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You need to use FVF like this:

```
D3DFVF_XYZ|D3DFVF_TEX1|D3DFVF_DIFFUSE
```

and to enable using the vertex color by:

```
m_pDevice9->SetRenderState(D3DRS_COLORVERTEX, TRUE);

m_pDevice9->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DIFFUSEMATERIALSOURCE, D3DMCS_COLOR1);
```

This is [another link](http://www.two-kings.de/tutorials/dxgraphics/dxgraphics07.html), showing more details about how to set the texture combiners. The example uses alpha combine, but it should be trivial to modify it to use color combiners instead.

Comment: Thanks, Bottom link was helpful but didn't solve the problem. Your code is for setting a diffuse material for use with D3D lights, do you know of any way to do this only messing with the TextureStageStates?

Comment: I think this is not possible. You need the lighting stage to take the color from the material and pass it to the pixel processing staging. That said, I am no longer expert on fixed function pipe, I am using only shaders now. Do you have any specific reason why not using shaders? Using shaders doing this would be easy (and easy to get more help).

Comment: I am quite good at HLSL, but not so much at fixed-function... Unfortunately shaders aren't available on the systems I'm targetting.